# How to get an array of referenced entity ids from an entity reference field

Tags: 8, entities

I have a `entity_reference` field with `BaseFieldDefinition::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED` cardinality. I want a list of referenced entity ids.
I know that I can get all the referenced entities by calling `$x->referencedEntities()`, but I want only the ids to get the entities loaded later. Currently I am doing this:

```
  $a = [];
  foreach ($entity->autoren as $v) {
    $a[] = $v->target_id;
  }
  $this->setCurrentAnwaltReferenzen($a);
```

Does anyone know a better solution like it was in D7 (->raw())?

Thanks

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As an alternative you can do it in one line with an array function instead of a loop:

```
$ids = array_column($entity->autoren->getValue(), 'target_id');
```

Edit: Use `getValue()` to only get the array of the field.