# How to get tid on behalf of node id (nid) in Drupal 8?

Tags: theming, nodes, entities, 8, taxonomy-terms

I am new in `Drupal 8`. I have created a node with `category (taxonomy)`. Now I don't understand how to get `tid` by using `nid`. I am using `$node->body->value` to get the body field value and use `{{ body }}`. But to get category id if I use `$node->field_category->value`, it will display `Null` in debugging mode.

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  $variables['body'] = $node->body->value;    // Working fine
  $cat_id = $node->field_category->value;    // Its showing null
  kint($cat_id);
}
```

So can anyone please tell me how can I get the `category id (tid)` of a node?

Answer (score 3):

A reference field doesn't have a property `value`. You can use `entity` to load the term or `target_id` to get the term id:

```
$tid = $node->field_tags->target_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But $node->field_tags->target_id get only one tid. What will I do if there are multiple taxonomy for a node?

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207699/how-to-get-an-array-of-referenced-entity-ids-from-an-entity-reference-field

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the items like this:

```
foreach ($node->field_category as $item) {
  $tids[] = $item->target_id;
}
```

or get the entities like this:

```
$terms = $node->get('field_category')->referencedEntities();
```