# getting a target_id value for for users in particular node drupal 8

Tags: hooks

i want to display a taget_id values for user in node's field but i can't print them , this is what I have done in the hook :

```
 $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node && $node->bundle() == 'MynodeType') {
    $members = $node->field_members->getValue();
    $members_ids = [];
    $current_user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $user_id = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load($current_user->id());

    foreach ($members as $member){
      $members_ids[] = $member['target_id'];
      echo $members_ids; // why this is not like (1,8,....)?
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Stackoverflow. Are you using PHPStorm like editor with xDebug mode enabled? It helps a lot. By putting breakpoint & see what result you are getting. . Please try `$member_ids = array_map(function ($member) {
        return $member['target_id'];
      }, $node->get('members')->getValue());`

Comment: or `$members_ids = array_column($node->field_members->getValue(), 'target_id');` see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207715/47547

Comment: @4k4 thank you so much

Comment: @Julia thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this one has to be solved this way

```
  $members = $node->field_members;
  foreach ($members as $member) {
      $members_ids[] = $member->getValue()['target_id'];
  }
```

Comment: Error : Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList::getTarget()

Comment: @drupalcoding updated answer.