# Compare a single value entity reference field to a multi-value entity reference field

Tags: 8, users

The article entity has an unlimited multi-value Taxonomy reference field `field_article_countries` referencing the Taxonomy vocabulary `Countries`and the User entity has a single value Taxonomy reference field `field_user_countries` which referencing the same taxonomy vocabulary `Countries`.

Programmatically, and comparing to one specific Article, I want to load all users that has have their `field_user_countries` value = to one of the values available inside the multi-value Taxonomy reference field `field_article_countries`.

**Example:**
Say **Article "ABC"** has the `field_article_countries` with values:

- Paris
- Spain
- London
- Italy

**User "A"** has `field_user_countries` set to:

- Spain

**User "B"** has `field_user_countries` set to:

- Italy

and **User "C"** has `field_user_countries` set to:

- Turkey

I want programmatically, and based on **Article "ABC"**, to load only User A & User B.

**Below is my code:**

```
// Get in array, a list of all "Article Countries" available for the loaded article.
$Article_Countries = $article->field_article_countries->getString();

    // Get Entity Manager to build your query
    $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('user');

    // Get all Users satisfing your conditions
    // For Condition Parameters @See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditions
    $uids = $storage->getQuery()
      ->accessCheck(FALSE)
      //->condition1
      //->condition2
      ->condition('field_user_countries', $Article_Countries, 'IN')
      ->execute();

    // Load all User entities according to their IDs
    $users = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::loadMultiple($uids);

    // Loop through loaded users.  
    foreach ($users as $user) {

    // Do something here.

}
```

**The problem** is that only one user is being loaded and not all users !

Any idea what is wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Article_Countries = $article->field_article_countries->getString();`

This returns a string

`->condition('field_user_countries', $Article_Countries, 'IN')`

[From the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditions#s-using-in-not-in), `condition` with `IN` accepts an array.

So, you need `$Article_Countries` to be an array of entity IDs. My first thought was `$article->field_article_countries->referencedEntities()` to get an array of objects, and then foreach them to build an array of IDs, but that's a bit round-the-houses. So I searched for a neater way and found this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/207715/89581 which suggests:

`$ids = array_column($entity->field->getValue(), 'target_id');`